Is it a good idea to use CompletableFuture in combination with StructuredTaskScope?
I already have an implementation using CompletableFuture with Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor as executorService.
For example, I have a code block,
CompletableFuture<MyClass> myAsyncMethod() {
  CompletableFuture<MyClass> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> myTask(), 
  executorService)
  .thenCompose(result -> {
   // some other processing
  }
 return future;

}


Can I do the same thing with StructuredTaskScope in java 21? I want to do it because I heard StructuredTaskScope prevents resource leak and manages virtual threads better than other options available in Java.
I want to do the above thing like this,
CompletableFuture<MyClass> myAsyncMethod() {
 try(var scope = StructuredTaskScope.shutdownOnFailure()){
    CompletableFuture<MyClass> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> myTask(), 
     executorService)

   scope.fork(future::join);
   scope.join();
   future.thenCompose(result -> {
     // some other processing
   }
   return future;
 } catch(InterruptedExeception e) { //handle it }

}

I am just asking whether it really helps to prevent resource leak and handle virtual thread lifeCycles more effectively if I use StructuredTaskScope and CompletableFuture together.
Please share your valuable thoughts on this.
Thanks.

What are you going to achieve , passing CompletableFuture.join to scope.fork? Couldn't you pass to it myTask() directly? With your design, two virtual threads will be started: by executorService created by Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor  and by scope.fork itself. Not necessarily a big deal as they are cheap, but what do you gain with such design?

Hi @igor.zh,
thanks for the comment. I am trying to reduce thread leak. I am not sure about using StructuredTaskScope with completableFuture actually reduces it or not. That's why i asked the question.
Thanks

Understood. Is there any way you could demonstrate your resource leak? How it manifests itself? Do you have  some MRE? Is it a memory leak? Or a leak of some limited resource like JDBC Connection? Is it specific for virtual thread only? Resource leak looks like a different issue. On what source which says that virtual thread or Structured Concurrency can prevent resource leaks do you rely upon?

It sounds more like a hypothetical question without an actual resource leak problem.

Actually, I am kinda new to this things and not sure which one is better. I actually had thread leak problem and handled it programmatically. I am sorry that I created  confusion between resource leak and thread leak. your valuable opinions helped me understand both CompletableFuture and StructuredTaskScope better.
Thanks to all.

The main property of a structured task scope is that all asynchronous tasks have completed by the time, the scope ends. This is the opposite of a method returning a future describing a potentially still ongoing computation.
You shouldn’t design you code around some hearsay about a thing being “somehow better” without understanding the thing. Your code trying to bring those two incompatible things together, one of them not even understood, unsurprisingly makes no sense at all.
You are starting an asynchronous operation but waiting for its completion, which is as good as not executing it asynchronously in the first place. The subsequent thenCompose(result -> …), invoked on an already completed future, will evaluate the function within the caller’s thread. You also added the bug of not returning the result of thenCompose to the caller but the already completed future which will not reflect the result of thenCompose.
Even in your original code, the thread evaluating the function passed to thenCompose is unspecified. It might be a thread belonging to executorService but it may also be the caller thread. In the end, there is no point in separating the invocation of myTask() and “// some other processing” here. Just write them into one function.
Note that one advantage of virtual threads is that you can stop composing stages into complex hard-to-debug stages but use a simple code flow instead:
// assuming executorService uses virtual threads
CompletableFuture<MyClass> myAsyncMethod() {
  return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    var result = myTask();
    var otherFuture = /* some other processing */
    return otherFuture.join(); // no big deal on a virtual thread
  }, executorService);
}

The virtual thread’s life cycle is very simple. It will be created, then execute your task, and die afterwards. It’s intended to be that simple and thus not clear what kind of improvement you are expecting from using StructuredTaskScope.

I don't think people should be discouraged from using. StructuredTaskScope. Whenever it fits their programming model (which it does not always do. We had a nice discussion on applicability of  StructuredTaskScope/ScopedValue when you were outtatown). The other thing is that using Structuring Concurrency just to avoid some resource leaks seems to me a strange idea.

I’m not discouraging anyone from using StructuredTaskScope. It just doesn’t fit this use case at all. I can even see where the idea of preventing resource leaks for a task that fits the structured task scope comes from.

Ohh? And where from? Plainly from the name of construct: try-with-resource? :)  Well, indeed, StructuredTaskScope will be closed, but it does not mean much. In conjunction with the usage (by default) of "born-and-die" virtual threads it indeed cleans up some state like ThreadLocals,but other than that...

A structure task scope allows to enforce that all subtasks have completed at the end of the scope, so there can’t be jobs dangling around holding resources. Look at the OP’s second example containing future.thenCompose(result -> …); return future; which does already have such a problem. In fact, even the Stream API has such a problem in the exceptional case.

Yeah, that's what I basically thought. But the fact that a task is not dangling does not guarantee that all the resources it held are freed - it is responsibility of the task, not scope. Task is not OS process, which resources are generally freed when the process exits/is killed.

@igor.zh of course, there’s nothing preventing you from doing it wrong and there never will be. But combining StructuredTaskScope with try-with-resource allows you to write very robust code in a very simple way, if the use case fits. I’m not the one saying that switching to StructuredTaskScope was a magic bullet preventing leaks, I just said, I can see where this idea comes from.

StructuredTaskScope is indeed a nice feature of Structured Concurrency, but the rationale of its combination with CompletableFuture would depend on how the latter is used.
In the snippet, you brought in the question,  two virtual threads will be started per single task. First thread is started by executorService which is returned by Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor method - and that first will actually execute your myTask method. StructuredTaskScope.fork method under the hood also starts a thread - and that second will just execute first one. While this design will not render erroneous behavior, and even if virtual threads are cheap, such duplication serves no purpose and the code looks unnecessarily convoluted.
All the advantages of virtual threads will be gained if just to pass to StructuredTaskScope.fork your myTask method.
If your myAsyncMethod still needs to return a CompletableFuture instance, for compatibility with previous design or for other reason, you may wrap the result:
import java.util.concurrent.StructuredTaskScope.Subtask;
import java.util.concurrent.StructuredTaskScope.Subtask.State;
    
    public CompletableFuture<MyClass> myAsyncMethod() throws InterruptedException {
        try (var scope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure()) {
            final Subtask<MyClass> task = scope.fork(() -> myTask());
            scope.join();
            return task.state() == State.FAILED ? CompletableFuture.failedFuture(task.exception())
                : CompletableFuture.completedFuture(task.get());// assume task is either failed or succeeded
        } 
    }

To summarize, it is OK to wrap the result of execution of StructuredTaskScope.Subtask into CompletableFuture, but the usage of CompletableFuture asynchronous methods, which involves Executor/ExecutorService,  makes no sense.
As for resource leaking you are concerned of, StructuredTaskScope cannot prevent memory leaks or leaks of other critical resources like JDBC Connections.

You gain no advantage of virtual threads at all when all you’re doing, is spawning exactly one task and waiting immediately at the caller’s thread for its completion. The scope.join() blocks the caller’s thread which may be a platform thread.

@Holger,  in this exact scenario - yes, of course. I took the OP's snippet just as a snippet, assuming that in real life there will be many tasks. Also I probably should have said: advantages of Structured Concurrency, first of all.
